# How to handle hardware button "Back" on Tizen platform using EFL library

Tags: event-handling, tizen, tizen-native-app, efl

I use EFL library to develop applications for Tizen platform. I need to implement event handler for hardware button "Back".

In native Tizen API it is done pretty simple. But I have no idea how can I do this in EFL library.

I tried to do it using the following way:

```
evas_object_event_callback_add( obj, EVAS_CALLBACK_KEY_DOWN, on_key_down, NULL );
```

But it doesn't work.

Could anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of EVAS_CALLBACK_KEY_DOWN`and`evas_object_event_callback_add()`,

- use `ea_object_event_callback_add`
- use `EA_CALLBACK_BACK` for back button
- and `EA_CALLBACK_MORE` for menu button
  but you need to include one header file, unfortunately I forgot the header file name 
  some thing efl-util.h or something, you can make a search in header files

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK the thing is that  EFL uses queues for processing events. That means that callbacks are called one by one: the first should return PASS_ON (or something) for the next callback for the same event to be run.

So, there may be another callback that does not allow the dispatch of the event.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Ecore_Event_Handler *handler;
handler = ecore_event_handler_add(ECORE_EVENT_KEY_DOWN, hardware_key_down_cb, NULL);
```

In **hardware_key_down_cb()** callback function, check for key name '**XF86Stop**' Ecore_Event_Key to handle back key event.

Answer (score 0):

use eext_object_event_callback_add(Evas_Object * obj,eext_callback_type type,callback_fun,NULL)
and in call back function you can write your requirement